# Bake not saving

Tags: fluid-simulation, cache

I'm still trying to light my monkey head on fire. I figured out how to bake the data but when I click off of the fluid tab in simulations it disappears. How do I get my settings to save?
If someone could provide screenshots for this explanation that would be great

Solution: Save the .blend file and pack it together with the "Cache-Folder" to upload it together. Later you can unpack it and only need to select the right folder when opening the .blend file to skip baking anew.

Comment: It disappears when you click off the fluid tab? What kind of cache you are using? _Replay_ or any other? To have it saved permanently you need to use either _Modular_ or _All_, then you have to bake the cache and it is saved in a folder which you can specify. Of course if you place your blend file somewhere else afterwards and the path is specified in a relative way so it cannot be found anymore, then Blender will bake it new... but that's the same in any other software that can use relative paths.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. While answering your own question is possible and even encouraged, it should be done respecting the site structure. Could you break this up into two posts, rephrasing the problem to read like an actual question or expose a problem, while the solution is written as separate answer in the proper section below? Maybe add a short description of the steps accompanied by a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)